# Создание файла в кодировке utf-8 средствами Lazarus

Tags: кодировка, pascal, freepascal, lazarus

Как создать файл в кодировке UTF-8 и записать в него текст? Весь интернет завален данными о том, как изменять кодировку переменных, но не слова о записи в файл.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На самом деле, в интернете есть всё, в том числе и эта информация. Но без [помощи](http://www.freepascal.ru/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=10971#p94349) знающих людей найти её затруднительно, так что делюсь.

```
var
  RawString: RawBiteString; //В этой строке будет текст, который мы собираемся писать в файл.
  FStream: TFileStream;
  //Другие переменные

begin
  //Формируем наполнение нашего файла. Результат должен быть строкой.
  RawString := ResultString; //Предположим, переменная ResultString
//хранит результат работы нашей программы, который мы хотим сохранить.
//Она может быть типа AnsiString или UnicodeString, - не важно,
//так как Lazarus преобразует строковые типы "на лету", при присваивании.
  SetCodePage(RawString, CP_NONE, False);
  SetCodePage(RawString, CP_UTF8, True); //Задаём кодовую страницу.
//Строки расположить именно в таком порядке, а не наоборот, как сказано в статье-источнике.
//Иначе, при создании файла, данные вы запишете в UTF-8, но кодировка самого файла останется
//неопределённой. Теоретически, кодовая страница может быть любая, но я не тестил.
  FStream:=TFileStream.Create('config.json', fmCreate); //Если мы создаём файл.
//Чтобы дописать в существующий используйте флаг fmOpenWrite.
  try
    FStream.WriteBuffer(RawString[1], Length(RawString)); //Пишем.
  finally // если при записи файла возникнет исключение (например, закончилось место)
// FStream всё равно будет освобожден.
    FStream.Free; //Кто не напишет эту строку - руки оторву.
//Тёмной стороной Силы, дистанционно.
  end;
end.
```