# Как создать файл через GitBush и сразу задать ему кодировку UTF-8

Tags: консоль, файловая-система, терминал

Господа, что бы в последствии не мучиться с кодировками на сайте или в каком либо проекте, я выработал для себя привычку, создаю простой файл .TXT в  котором сразу задаю ему кодировку utf-8 и когда мне надо создать какой-нибудь файл, я его копирую и в редакторе меняю название и расширения и получаю то, что мне надо...  Не совсем удобно, мне бы хотелось сразу в консоли  GitBush создать файл и задать ему кодировку UTF-8. "touch название.расширение" и как мне тут, если это возможно задать кодировку?

*Я нашел тут на сайте подобный вопрос, но не понял ничего, [Подобный вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/501758/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B5-utf-8-%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8-lazarus)*

Comment: Технически у файлов нет никакой кодировки и она нигде не хранится, поэтому сразу «задать кодировку UTF-8» пустому файлу невозможно. Файл — это всего лишь упорядоченный набор байт, который интерпретируется программами как они умеют. Если ваша программа-текстовый редактор не позволяет выставить кодировку по умолчанию UTF-8 для пустых (и не только) файлов — меняйте редактор.

Comment: Хотя у файлов иногда бывает [BOM](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%80_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8_%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2), но от него проблем больше чем пользы, так что лучше просто поменяйте свой редактор

Comment: Это sublime, если честно у него проблема с кодировками...  Но мне он нравиться  по всем остальным показателям

Comment: я вот как раз смотрю настройки своего sublime и у него по умолчанию кодировка как раз UTF-8, никогда с ним проблем не было, хз че у вас тогда

Comment: @andreymal,  тогда разъясни, когда создаю файл с терминала командой touch,  а потом  открываю файл в редакторе и выбираю в sublime`Е сохнанить в кодировке utf-8, то он все ровно остается  в кодировке ANSI. я что-то делаю не так?

Comment: Не знаю, я не юзал sublime в винде. Но, быть может, в винде просто кодировка по умолчанию другая и достаточно будет прописать вместо неё UTF-8 https://i.stack.imgur.com/r4wlr.png

Comment: у меня в win10 тоже самое.. по умолчанию utf-8, а вот  когда преобразовываешь в utf-8 Notepad++ все отлично меняется

Comment: может какой то плагин есть для  sublime`а, надо посмотреть?

Comment: Может это просто баг и/или у вас старая версия?)

Comment: @andreymal, версия последняя, и все тоже самое в каждой сборке, уже 3 год работаю в  sublime

Comment: Даже не знаю, поставил sublime в вин10 в виртуалке — [всё отлично сохраняется в utf-8](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PQ3ezBHoT2E)

Comment: @andreymal, может я что то делаю не так или не правильно понимаю? Вот например, я создаю файл .txt потом открываю его и нажимаю "сохранить как" и сохраняя выбираю кодировку utf-8, если файл создаю в sublime или в gitbush и в sublime выбираю сохранить в кодировке utf-8, а потом открываю его в блокноте и нажимаю "сохранить как", то мне там показывает, что файл сохранен в кодировке ANSI? я в чем то не прав?

Comment: Если файл состоит только из английских символов, то и UTF-8, и ANSI, и CP1251, и CP866, и KOI8-R — всё это получается одна и та же кодировка. У всех них первые 128 символов (куда попадают английские буквы, цифры, знаки препинания и некоторые спецсимволы) кодируются одними и теми же кодами ASCII, в результате чего отличить эти кодировки друг от друга в английском тексте невозможно.

Comment: @andreymal  посмотри ответ, а ты говоришь не возможно?))))

Comment: Посмотри мой второй комментарий, я там именно об этом и говорил :)

Comment: Ну и какие проблемы, поделись?

Comment: Уже поделился в комментарии к ответу

Comment: Если уж зашла речь про BOM, то в Sublime вполне есть «File → Save with Encoding → UTF-8 with BOM»

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если надо создать файл с BOM для UTF-8, то надо записать в него 3 байта: `EF BB BF`.

Судя по всему это можно сделать так:

```
echo -n -e '\xEF\xBB\xBF' > smth.txt
```

PS: Команда записи байт взята из [этого ответа](//unix.stackexchange.com/a/118251).

Comment: всегда знал, что ты умница, такого как еще поискать )))))))

Comment: Проблемы замалчиваем? :) Мусор в некоторых редакторах, headers already sent в php, проблемы с чтением таких файлов в питоне, всё такое)

Comment: @andreymal, я просто ответил на заданный вопрос. Если у тебя есть другой ответ - напиши его.

Comment: Считаю такое отношение недостойным качественной базы знаний, к какой стремится SO. Нужно предупреждать о последствиях, а не тупо всё вываливать.

Comment: Для txt-файлов использование bom - это нормально. Для каких-то других - надо уже конкретно разбираться. Проблема про php вроде неактуальна, т. к. там 1024 символа дефаултный буфер.

Comment: @Qwertiy на данный момент меня интересует только файлы html css js svg, вроде все ок.  но а какие могут быть проблемы?

Comment: @Air с перечисленными скорее всего никаких, браузеры (современные) вроде нормально обрабатывают BOM

Comment: @Air, BOM перед doctype'ом в каких-то версиях IE приводил к quirks-режиму. В php при отключенном буфере шлются эти 3 байта и ты уже не можешь послать http-заголовки, если json начинается с BOM, то JSON.parse падает (по крайней мере в node.js, в браузере не проверял, что происходит с BOM). Других проблем мне неизвестно. Зато текстовые редакторы всегда правильно знают кодировку.

Comment: Да нормально, но как я помню, это было давно, когда начал изучать web то там писали, что обязательно сохранять файл в кодировке utf-8 без bom

Comment: @Air и я настоятельно советую продолжать сохранять utf-8 без bom и не обращать внимание на всякий ANSI-бред, который пишут всякие блокноты, и вообще не юзать блокноты, в sublime и notepad++ всё норм :)

Comment: @andreymal, почему бы тебе не написать этот совет отдельным ответом с перечислением того, как может навредить bom? Я бы даже ему плюс поставил.

Comment: @Qwertiy потому что это не будет ответом на поставленный вопрос) Ну или будет, но по основной сути дубликатом данного, а я не хочу дубликаты. Этот ответ ответом вполне является, а я просто придираюсь к его некоторой неполноте

Comment: @andreymal, согласен с Qwertiy, напиши ответом, будет полезно почитать у кого вопрос возникнет

Comment: @andreymal, а мне кажется, это был бы нормальный ответ.

Comment: @andreymal, тогда давай поставим все точки над i когда в консоли я создаю файл командой touch  и в самом редакторе выбираю преобразовать файл в кодировке utf-8 без бом, то этого достаточно и не стоит обращать внимание, что когда я открываю его в блокноте и он в кодировке ANSI это ничего не значит?

Comment: @Air если файл пустой или только с [ASCII-символами](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII), то это лишь значит, что в блокноте кодировка по умолчанию ANSI (точнее, это на самом деле вроде Windows-1251), и ничего больше. Если не трогать блокнот и сидеть в notepad++/sublime, то всё должно быть хорошо. А если однажды таки приспичит создать файл со строго UTF-8, то вот Qwertiy ответ написал :) Если в файле будут не-ASCII символы (русский текст, например), то даже блокнот покажет UTF-8.

Comment: @andreymal, все понятно, значит достаточно и sublima... Благодарю

Comment: [А вот и проблемы с BOM подвезли](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/731392) :D

Comment: @andreymal, да напиши наконец ответ...