# Проблемы с json_decode

Tags: php, json

Имеется следующий json объект:

```
{
    "ИД": "0f126618-6606-11e7-b4c8-005056c00008",
    "НоменклатураИД": "af0412c1-2feb-11e7-8c78-005056c00008",
    "Наименование": "1712 Миа",
    "ДатаИзменения": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
    "Описание": "",
    "Meta_title": "",
    "Meta_description": "",
    "Meta_keyword": "",
    "Теги": "",
    "ТканьРегион": "1712 Миа",
    "СайтАртикул": "1712",
    "СайтСтиль": "Жаккардовый",
    "СайтАкция": "Нет",
    "СайтПоказыватьВМагазине": "Да"
}
```

Функция json_decode выводит NULL при попытке вардампа
Но при этом вот такой json объект она нормально декодирует:

```
{
    "ИД": "8574a44b-2b1a-11e7-8c78-005056c00008",
    "Наименование": "КПБ \"Дуэт\" [Бамбук-жаккард)",
    "НаименованиеПолное": "КПБ \"Дуэт\" [Бамбук-жаккард)",
    "Артикул": "360/0034295",
    "ЕдиницаИзмеренияКод": "796",
    "ЕдиницаИзмеренияНаименование": "шт",
    "ВестиУчетПоХарактеристикам": true
}
```

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: В текстовом виде ваш JSON валидный и json_decode его разбирает нормально. А null он возвращает, если разобрать не удалось - возможно причина в каких-то непечатных символах. В чём была ошибка - могут подсказать функции json_last_error_msg и json_last_error. Правда помнится сообщение об ошибке от них всё равно не очень внятное.

Comment: ну да, совсем не внятное (Syntax error)

Comment: Откуда json поступает? Запишите его как есть куда-нибудь в файлик и посмотрите в hex представлении. `hd` команда в linux, например.

Comment: только я не на линуксе сижу(

Comment: возможно это как то связано с curl, я json данные через него получаю с сервера, просто когда я получаю json при помощи js (ajax) таких проблем нет

Comment: ну значит возьмите любую из программ показывающих hex под свою ОС. Скорее это как-то связано с приложением, с которого вы json загружаете. Ключи на кириллице в хорошем коде штука исключительная

Comment: просто странно что проблемы именно в php, а в js все норм

Comment: в общем я через notepad++ перевел обе json строки в HEX, и понял, что разница в символе "{" в самом начале, не вижу другого выхода, кроме как вырезать его и добавлять нужный

Comment: а в чём именно различие в hex? Добавьте это в сам вопрос, кстати

Comment: Валидный символ "{" = 7B, а символ который я получаю с сервера EFBBBF7B

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам присылают метку BOM - [`byte order mark`](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%80_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8_%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2). Конкретно EFBBBF характерна для UTF8.

Но `json_decode` не ожидает такой метки и потому считает документ невалидным. Метку можно безопасно удалять:

```
if (substr_compare($json, "\xEF\xBB\xBF", 0) > 0) {
    $json = substr($json, 3);
}
```

Вообще от этот метки часто проблемы встречаются. Нередко стандарты кодирования (`PSR` стандарты PHP в том числе) требуют не использовать эту метку.